# Set Auto-Rotate Enabled/Disabled Android

Tags: android, button, android-intent, rotation

I am working on an Android app, for which I would like the user to be able to press a button which either enables or disables auto-rotate. How can I do this with an Intent? I'd imagine I would somehow need to change ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION to 0 or 1, but I don't know how to do this precisely. I hope maybe one of you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can toggle Rotation ON/OFF using ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION as :

```
if  (android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1){
    android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0);
    Toast.makeText(Rotation.this, "Rotation OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
else{
    android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 1);
    Toast.makeText(Rotation.this, "Rotation ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

and finally add `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` permission in Manifast

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but how do I use this in an intent? I can't use onClick in my app.

Comment: intent means tell more about what you want

Comment: Note: starting from API 23 (Android M - 6.x) , you need to request the permission , as such: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32083622/878126