# How to check if auto-rotate screen setting is ON/OFF in Android 4.0+

Tags: java, android

I think each android device has an abitily to on/off auto-rotating function. 
Usually you can find it in `settings->display->auto-rotate on/off`. How can I read this setting state from my application? How can I access to this setting value? If you can share a code snipped i'd be very appreciate it.

Comment: what did you do by getting that status of device. I mean what do you want to do exactly by getting that?

Comment: Check on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870933/set-auto-rotate-enabled-disabled-android

Comment: Go through this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908048/enable-and-disable-auto-rotate-programatically
it may be useful for you

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Hope this code snippet helps you out:-

```
@Override      
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rotation ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rotation OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
if (android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1) {
    Toast.makeText(Rotation.this, "Rotation ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(Rotation.this, "Rotation OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public static void setAutoOrientationEnabled(ContentResolver resolver, boolean enabled)
        {
              Settings.System.putInt( context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, enabled ? 1 : 0);
        }
```