# Android 6 Marshmallow: requests for some specific permissions are instantly denied with no ui shown

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Using official AVD rev. 3

Calling this:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{"android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CREDENTIALS);
```

Fires immediately:

```
onRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)
```

And resulting code is `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`

Anyone has a fix?

UPDATE:
Known to be affected:

```
Manifest.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS (solved, see Sam's answer)
android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS (solved, read Update 2)
READ_SMS
```

UPDATE 2:
See excellent accepted answer. Essentially, USE_CREDENTIALS is a safe permission now. Beats me why sdk not simply return PERMISSION_GRANTED for it...

Comment: Did you see the dialog?

Comment: Do you have the permission defined in the manifest ?

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan no dialog. onResult is called instantly

Comment: @yoah good thought. but copied permission directly from the manifest. it is still there

Comment: Did you solve? I can reproduce here too but didn't find a solution.

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan not solved. i assume it's a bug in the compat lib...

Comment: @rothschild86 This is strange, because `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` works fine. Yours and `Manifest.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` and `Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` are not working

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan ah, good find. so different permissions follow different logical paths... interesting...

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan just noticed that USE_CREDENTIALS is not even in the global list of permissions... but the ones you mention - they are. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Yes, i've double check and its OK. I will research more about this.

Comment: READ_SMS seems to be affected too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to these pages: [permissions by protection level](https://gist.github.com/andhie/70098e17ded91eee19e9) and [protection level definitions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestPermission_protectionLevel).

> Manifest.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
>
> Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS

These fall under the protection level "signature|appop|pre23|preinstalled" which means that only same-signature apps (system signed basically), app operators, apps that target below API level 23 and presintalled apps can have these.

> android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS

This is only needed on API level 22 and below. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20boolean,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29).

Also you should check out the [Behavior Changes](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html).

Comment: It seems that WRITE_SETTINGS can be granted using the specific menu under "Apps" on android M. If the app target < 23 the permission is granted by default, if the app target is >= 23 the permission is not granted by default. The problem is that with these kind of permissions, the checkSelfPermissions & co. seems not work.

Comment: I think it's there to allow the user to revoke this permission from pre-23 apps. Since you cannot access it through the API, it doesn't matter whether you can grant it in the settings menu.

Comment: @rothschild86 So how did you solve it ? I keep getting permission denied without a dialog.

Comment: @Danpe which permission are you dealing with?

Comment: @Danpe this seems to be a known issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189841 and it doesn't seem to be fixed as of yet. I'm using `Location` permissions and no dialog shows up even though it's stated that this is "Dangerous permission" (see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `WRITE_SETTINGS`, CommonsGuy has provided a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32083622/238753

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've got it sorted. I had this same symptom with a more foolish cause.

I had my uses-permission nodes INSIDE my application node in my manifest. This seemed to work on 22 or less but moving to 23 seemed to not recognize it and thus auto deny the permission.

Hopefully this helps someone else stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

first check for Marshmellow version then paste this in your code after changing the activity name

```
if (!android.provider.Settings.System.canWrite(RingdroidEditActivity.this)) {
                    Intent intentt = new     Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                intentt.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + RingdroidEditActivity.this.getPackageName()));
                intentt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intentt);
            }
```

This will take you to the permission page of the app and ask the user to give permission

WRITE_SETTINGS after marshmellow has been changed
this will work
to see the example check this application