# ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork in Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to get the new `ConnectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(Network)` using `ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork(NetworkRequest, ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)`

The reason is to force the app to call the future request in some specific network, which doesn't have a internet connectivity (it's a local hardware communication network). At this point, the system is sending the requests over 3G/4G network and never reach the desired Wifi network, because this network doesn't respond the [connectivity check](http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204) that android call.

When I call the `requestNetwork` method, I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: com.xyz.app was not granted  either of these permissions: android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.
```

I try to call the new method to request permission available in Android 6.0:

```
 requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WIFI);
```

But the callback is always `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`.

I put both of these permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, without success.

Notice: The `Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` is not in the [Permissions Groups](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#permission-groups).

Comment: Indeed non of those 2 permissions are tagged "dangerous". No idea why it won't work. But you'r link to "connectivity check" code seems broken, so I can't have a look at it.

Comment: @shkschneider actually I saw the link in the logcat for each network connected. It's a simple blank page this 204 http result. maybe this can change dinamically...

Comment: `WRITE_SETTINGS` is handled via [a different mechanism](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32083622/115145). In terms of `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE`, I am not sure what the story is there -- the docs claim it is `normal`, but my 6.0-equipped Nexus 5 says it is `signature`.

Comment: @CommonsWare `normal` and `signature` should be treated equally anyway, right?

Comment: @shkschneider: Sorry, but I do not know what you mean by that. You can't employ a `signature` permission unless you are signed by the same signing key as whatever is defending itself with that permission, or unless there is some other mechanism (e.g., how `WRITE_SETTINGS` and `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` are handled now).

Comment: @CommonsWare Was talking about https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#system-apps. But nevermind my comment, your comment is entirely true.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks!!! I'll take a look in your previous answer. Indeed, my nexus 5 also treated as `signature`.

Comment: Is there any bug raised for this? Seeing the same error for my app while connectivityManager.requestNetwork API

Comment: @Rupali look at https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2993&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208863/some-permissions-protectionlevel-seems-wrongly-documented-or-implemented/32519310#32519310 Whats the status in official ROM?

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder No resolution until now. I'm using the target API 22 to make it work with previous permission model (in AndroidManifest.xml only)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure if this was intended by Google, but the following is the behavior I'm seeing:

`CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` seems to always be denied (as noted in the comments, its a signature permission) but it also doesn't seem to matter.  My `ConnectivityManager` network requests all seem to be gated by `WRITE_SETTINGS` only - so if you have `WRITE_SETTINGS` you don't need `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE`.

As noted in comments, you do this differently than other permissions, using:

```
 Intent goToSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
 goToSettings.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + Context.getPackageName()));
 startActivity(goToSettings);
```

And after that, my `ConnectivityManager` network requests were peachy.

---

To check if the permission is already granted before calling the `ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS` activity, this answer has the solution using 
[Settings.System.canWrite(Context)](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#canWrite%28android.content.Context%29)

[Can't get WRITE_SETTINGS permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083410/android-m-6-0-ringtonemanager-manifest-permission-write-settings-error/32083622#32083622)

---

UPDATE: as of Android 6.0.1, `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` is auto granted when requested in your manifest file.  The above `WRITE_SETTINGS` checks are only required for 6.0

Comment: It works, thanks for your answer! But I notice that even the user accept the `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission manually, next time I launch the same activity the result of the permissions still marked as `PERMISSION_DENIED`. I need to apply this solution before calling the Intent again (avoid go to settings when it's already enabled) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083410/android-m-6-0-ringtonemanager-manifest-permission-write-settings-error/32083622#32083622

Comment: This is no longer needed in Android 6.0.1. `WRITE_SETTING` and `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` are no longer the same thing.

Answer (score 14):

This was an Android 6.0 bug. It's fixed in Android 6.0.1, `requestNetwork()` can be called if you request `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` in the manifest. No need to call `requestPermissions()`, it's a `normal` permission.

Comment: Nice, this sounds really good! I'll take a look in my sources and upgrade to 6.0.1 and check it! Thanks!