# Some Permissions' protectionLevel seems wrongly documented or implemented

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm running through many permissions tagged `PROTECTION_NORMAL` and `PROTECTION_DANGEROUS` in a `ListView`. Upon click my application calls `ActivityCompat.requestPermission()`.

All permissions I tested (by that I mean all `normal` and `dangerous` [permissions for API-7 and above I could find](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE)) are working fine on my Emulator, except for some:

- `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE`

Requesting `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` always returns `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` (without even prompting). **I would expect** it granted by default since it's flagged `normal`, or if the documentation is wrong, to be prompted for it then.

- `GET_ACCOUNTS`

Requesting `GET_ACCOUNTS` works after prompting, but the documentation lists this permission as `normal` not `dangerous` (the dialog asks for "access your contacts"). **I would expect** it granted by default since it's flagged `normal` and not to be prompted for it.

- `READ_CELL_BROADCASTS`

Is [listed](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html) as a permission from the `SMS` permission group, but that permission does not exists in the `Manifest.permission` package.

Yes, all permissions are in my *AndroidManifest.xml*.

**Questions**

1. Am I the only one to have this?
2. Is it emulator-specific?
3. Is the documentation faulty or is the preview build wrong?

Comment: FYI `GET_ACCOUNTS` is part of the `CONTACTS` permissions group so is considered to be a `dangerous` permission in API 23.

Comment: Yes, the bug was reported and the documentation will be fixed, as my answer explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Indeed they are.**

Turns out those are work-in-progress and mostly acknowledge bugs.

- https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2993
- https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3083

I posted a new bug for `GET_ACCOUNTS`, that was yet to be reported.

Mostly to be fixed for final release / documentation (aka NOT preview).

Comment: Issue #2993 is fixed in Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 1):

As of Marshmallow (since preview 3), introspection shows `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` has been moved to protection level `signature|appop|pre23|preinstalled`. Using `requestPermissions()` will not work on this. It seems the documentation is not up-to-date. Actually, `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` has also been merged with `WRITE_SETTINGS`, as suggested by the logcat output:

```
was not granted  either of these permissions: android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.
```

As a user, you may grant both permissions by going into "Settings / Apps / Configure apps / Modify system settings" and turn on "Allow modify system settings". Your app may trigger the right activity directly (although that's a pretty rude user experience):

```
Uri selfPackageUri = Uri.parse("package:" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS, selfPackageUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Finally, you may check if this is allowed by calling [`Settings.System.canWrite()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#canWrite(android.content.Context)).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you provide a link to the source that indicates the new protection level? Thanks!

Comment: Just tried the code to open the write settings activity on an early OEM M build, and it couldn't resolve the intent. Seems this might be only partially supported (via OEMs). It did work on the Preview 3 AOSP build.

Comment: Search `permissions` array in a `PackageInfo` object corresponding to the system (`packageManager.getPackageInfo("android", packageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS)`). Once you've found the index of the permission you're interested in, get the `PermissionInfo`, it has a `protectionLevel` field.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for `requestPermission()` state that it should only be called for permissions which are `dangerous` protection level and *not* already granted. Are you calling `checkSelfPermission()` first and only requesting if it fails?

The current images are still previews, so it is possible that something is misbehaving. However, it stands to reason that if the docs state the APIs should only be called under certain conditions, they may misbehave if those conditions aren't met.

Comment: Protections levels are inconsistent between documentation and runtime code. And yes I call `checkSelfPermission()` before `requestPermission()`. For example `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` returns to me as `dangerous` (in code) and `checkSelfPermission()` return `DENIED` so I call `requestPermission()` that immediately returns `DENIED` without prompting.

Comment: Interesting. Definitely sounds like a bug, if suggest searching then logging it if not found in the preview big database.