# Getting "IllegalArgumentException: You cannot keep your settings in the secure settings" error

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, settings

This code:

```
 Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), POWER_KEY_DEFINITION, 1);
```

Generates the error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot keep your settings in the secure settings.
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:646)
    at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1595)
    at android.provider.Settings$System.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1965)
    at android.provider.Settings$System.putIntForUser(Settings.java:2070)
    at android.provider.Settings$System.putInt(Settings.java:2064)
    at com.example.sasho.timer2.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:155)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:892)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
```

Another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971846/settings-system-api-behaviour-in-android-api-level-23) provides an answer to the same error, they say "Settings.System is for platform-defined settings. You cannot put arbitrary settings in there, such as test.hemant.".

But the thing is in my case this isn't an arbitrary system setting that I'm putting. I know it exists in the TV box I'm working on because before I tried in any way to write over it or create it I checked with the Settings.getInt method to get its value and indeed there was a value. I used the remote control to change the corresponding setting and getInt reflected the change. How can I resolve the error? I do have the WRITE_SETTINGS and WRITE_SECURE__SETTINGS permissions in my manifest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35285034/1568530

Comment: Hello. I used that code but the same problem remains. Code dependent on the (Settings.System.canWrite(context)) clause executes so I guess I do have permission to write there.though still I get the same error

Comment: try to write some more commonly-used system settings, and check if it works. Probably there is just a list of settings which are allowed to write, and your `POWER_KEY_DEFINITION` is not in that list

Comment: POWER_KEY_DEFINITION is not in the usual list at all. But the device's manufacturer seems to have added it and is able to give it new values even though it's running android 7

Comment: Hi, was you able to solve this issue? I got the same situation with another Samsung properties after upgrading from Android 12 to Android 11

Comment: Sorry I don't remember and there isn't a way for me to check.