# Android security expression is thrown even after mentioned in manifest file

Tags: android

I'm using Android Studio 1.3.2 on win7(64-bit) machine, developing application with kitkat (API level 23).

I'm trying to set brightness using seekbar control and have mentioned permission in manifest file as below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Now i'm getting the below exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: com.sam.shmiandan.androidbrightness was not granted  this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
```

How can I solve below error ?

Comment: post your full manifest.xml code

Answer (score 1):

**

> Note : **You are using API 23 level which is not Kitkat.**

**

To use WRITE_SETTINGS, based on the docs:

1. Have the  element in the manifest as normal..

   [Call Settings.System.canWrite()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#canWrite%28android.content.Context%29) to see if you are eligible to write out settings.
2. If canWrite() returns false, start up the ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS activity so the user can agree there to allow your app to actually write to settings.
3. IOW, writing to settings is now a double-opt-in (agree to install, agree separately in Settings to allow), akin to device admin APIs, accessibility services, etc.

Also note that I have not tried using these yet — [this is based on research that I did yesterday on Android 6.0 changes](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/17/random-musings-android-6p0-sdk.html)

Reference : [Can't get WRITE_SETTINGS permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083410/android-m-6-0-ringtonemanager-manifest-permission-write-settings-error)