# Android signature permission

Tags: android, permissions

"android.permission.**WRITE_SETTINGS**" has signature level,but a normal app can also use it. so who can tell me something about it. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` allows an application to read or write the system settings.

You can request this permission in your app like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

(or like this for Android 6.0 only)

```
<uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083410/android-m-6-0-ringtonemanager-manifest-permission-write-settings-error/32083622#32083622) answer from @CommonsWare about `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission