# Android M requestPermissions(ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),don't show dialog？

Tags: android, permissions, runtime, android-6.0-marshmallow

AndroidManifest.xml has add it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

**ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()**

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
if (!(permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {

    } else {
        // do request the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                8);
    }
}
```

**onRequestPermissionsResult()**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 8: {
            // grantResults[0] = -1
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            } else {

            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

`requestPermissions(ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)` doesn't show any dialog, and `onRequestPermissionsResult` return -1.

Instead `requestPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)` is working correctly.

**another question**：[Android M 6.0 - Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32083622/703225)

Comment: Did you try to open the dialog for the first time? Did you checked the option "Never as again"?

Comment: reinstall the app, first time the shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() return false,the dialog still don't show.

Comment: src Github:https://github.com/captain-miao/Android_M_requestPermissions

Comment: another question [Android 6.0 Permission Denial: requires permission android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32083622/238753)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a typo in the `uses-permission` name, permission is with 3 *'s'*

Change from this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

to this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```