# How to set ringtone programmatically in oreo 8.0

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, ringtone, android-8.1-oreo

I can set ringtone programmatically between 4.0 to 6.0(Marshmallow) but not able to set after 6.0 (Marshmallow).

Can you please let me know how to fix this issue so that i can set ringtone to an Android Oreo 8.0 and 8.1 version device too?

```
  public void setRingtone(String filepath) {
        File ringtoneFile = new File(filepath);
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Ring");
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, ringtoneFile.length());
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
        //  content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Madonna");
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());

        getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
        Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, content);
        System.out.println("uri==" + uri);
        Log.i("TAG", "the ringtone uri is :" + newUri);
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Ringtone set success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Thank You.

Comment: give more discription when try to set ringtone in 8.0 whats error u face..

Comment: please, check above code for set ringtone @Ashvinsolanki. please upvote question.

Comment: whats error u face after run in 8.0 oreo

Comment: Problem is, that in android 8.0 you cannot get permission WRITE_SETTINGS anymore and you get security errors related to not having that permission (either that you don't have it or you ask for it and grant was denied).

Comment: This worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083410/cant-get-write-settings-permission

Answer (score -1):

Add URI permission on your project

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

create **xml**  folder in **res** and acreate **provider_path.xml** in **res/XML**
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if6pd.png)

### provider_paths.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    </paths>
```

Hope it helps