# My application doesn't use the internet connection on my Samsung J4 core so I cannot access database. It returns com.android.volley.TimeOutError

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest

I have included these lines in my manifest file:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE/>

Comment: what your apps does?

Comment: it is a login registration app

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083410/cant-get-write-settings-permission/32083622#32083622`